# 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, series

I am trying to convert a column of timestamps (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS) from a pandas dataframe to seconds.

Here is my current code:

```py
df['recorded_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['recorded_time'])
df['timestamp'] = df['recorded_time'].datetime.total_seconds() #creating a new column
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Can anyone point out where I may be missing a step?

Comment: Because it doesn't. `to_datetime` will return a `datetime64` value that doesn't have the same methods/attributes of a regular python datetime. You'll need to use the `.dt` accessor, so something like `df['timestamp'] = df['recorded_time'].dt.` but then `total_seconds()` is a `datetime.timedelta` method from python, so I don't really follow what you expect that to be doing, even if we translated it to pandas. Seconds from _when_?

Comment: @roganjosh  2019/01/01 00:00:00 would work... I was trying to follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430069/spatial-temporal-interpolation-in-python However, I was still getting the same attribute error.

Comment: What roganjosh is trying to say is that total seconds is a timedelta, this means it takes the total seconds between two timepoints. In this case you just have a timestamp (one time point). So it does not make sense to take the "total seconds". Total seconds from when or what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm using the [example you gave in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430069/spatial-temporal-interpolation-in-python) for the df. You cannot use regular `datetime.datetime` methods on pandas `datetime64` values without using the `.dt` accessor. In addition to the example you linked to, you said that you want `total_seconds` to refer to the base datetime of `2019/01/01 00:00:00`. A `timedelta` must always have some kind of reference point, otherwise it could be any arbitrary value.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lat':[15.13,12.14,13.215,11.1214,12.14], 
              'lon': [38.52, 37.536,39.86,38.536,37.536],
              'Datetime': pd.to_datetime(['2019-03-09 16:05:07',
                                          '2019-03-15 09:50:07',
                                          '2019-03-09 11:03:47',
                                          '2019-03-10 16:41:18',
                                          '2019-03-09 06:15:27']),
              'temp':[23,22,21,22,19]})

# We can just call it once to get a reference to your datum point
base_dt = pd.to_datetime('2019/01/01 00:00:00')

df1['seconds'] = (df1['Datetime'] - base_dt).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to convert datetime into numbers is to view it as `'int64'`:

```py
df['ns_since_UNIX_epoch'] = df['recorded_time'].view('int64')

# this is equivalent to 
(df['recorded_time'] - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')).dt.total_seconds() * 10**9
```

---

In general, to access datetime methods, use the `.dt` accessor on a pandas column; and to access string methods, use the `.str` accessor.

To see a list of all attributes of a pandas column or Series, call `dir()`. You can check the following:

```py
'datetime' in dir(pd.Series)          # False
'dt' in dir(pd.Series)                # True
'total_seconds' in dir(pd.Series.dt)  # True
```